# Why does this script not produce the console log when the form is submitted?

Tags: javascript, jquery

got a quick question (hopefully). I have this jQuery script that I am trying to get to produce each variable in text form when the form is submitted. However, it is not showing anything. I am not getting a problem in the debugger either. Any help or push in the right direction would be great.

```js
script.onload = function () {
    $("#form").submit(function(){
        var user = $(".userBox").text();
        var email = $(".emailBox").text();
        var pass = $(".passBox").text();
        var conPass = $(".conPassBox").text();
        console.log(user + " " + email + " " + pass + " " + conPass);
    });
}
```

```html
<main>
            <form id="form">
                <fieldset id="box">
                    <h1 class="signUpTitle">Universal Sign Up</h1>
                    <label for="user" class="user all">Username: </label>
                    <input required type="text" class="userBox textbox" name="user" maxlength="16" minlength="5"></br>
                    <label for="email" class="email all">Email: </label>
                    <input required type="email" class="emailBox textbox" name="email"></br>
                    <label for="pass" class="pass all">Password: </label>
                    <input required type="password" class="passBox textbox" name="pass" maxlength="20" minlength="8"></br>
                    <label for="conPass" class="conPass all" >Confirm password: </label>
                    <input required type="password" class="conPassBox textbox" name="conPass" maxlength="20" minlength="8"></br>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset id="terms">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="check">
                    <label for="terms" class="terms">Terms and Conditions</label></br>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset id="submit">
                    <input type="submit" class="submit">
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset id="signUp">
                    Already have an account? 
                    <a href="login.html" class="signUp">Sign in</a>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
            <script src="../src/account.js"></script>
        </main>
```

Comment: The form doesn’t have a `submit` event listener. Buttons cannot be submitted; only forms.

Comment: Did not know that, thank you. Sadly, I am still not seeing anything.

Comment: Please update your question with your latest code. Are there any errors in your dev tools? I'm seeing `script is not defined`

Comment: For input elements, it’s `.val`, not `.text`.

Comment: Also, `</br>` is invalid html.

Comment: Is your form submitting before you can see the console log?

Comment: Have you checked 'preserve log' in the console so that it's rtained between page loads?

Comment: Thank you SebastianSimon that fixed the variables. Thank you mykaf the </br> was invalid and I don't know why I had that and it is submitting before I can see the log. @RoryMcCrossan can you expand on that, I do not know what the preserve log is?

Comment: Normally the console is cleared whenever the page is unloaded between requests. To prevent that happening there is usually a 'Preserve logs' option within the devtools console which you can enabled. In Firefox, for example, it looks like this: https://i.imgur.com/xekPAGM.png

Comment: Thank you I found it, it does still clear my objects with each new page load even with preserve log on but thats ok. Im just going to look into different smaller ways of storage. It will be good practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The is being page reloaded, thereby resetting it to its original state, because the form is being submitted normally. You need to prevent the form from submitting by using `preventDefault()` on the event, which you define by adding the variable name you wish to use to the first argument of the function.

Also to get the input elements' values you use `.val()`, not `.text()`.

```js
$("#form").submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var user = $(".userBox").val();
  var email = $(".emailBox").val();
  var pass = $(".passBox").val();
  var conPass = $(".conPassBox").val();
  console.log(user + " " + email + " " + pass + " " + conPass);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="form">
  <fieldset id="box">
    <h1 class="signUpTitle">Universal Sign Up</h1>
    <label for="user" class="user all">Username: </label>
    <input required type="text" class="userBox textbox" name="user" maxlength="16" minlength="5">
    <label for="email" class="email all">Email: </label>
    <input required type="email" class="emailBox textbox" name="email">
    <label for="pass" class="pass all">Password: </label>
    <input required type="password" class="passBox textbox" name="pass" maxlength="20" minlength="8">
    <label for="conPass" class="conPass all">Confirm password: </label>
    <input required type="password" class="conPassBox textbox" name="conPass" maxlength="20" minlength="8">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset id="terms">
    <input type="checkbox" class="check">
    <label for="terms" class="terms">Terms and Conditions</label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset id="submit">
    <input type="submit" class="submit">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset id="signUp">
    Already have an account?
    <a href="login.html" class="signUp">Sign in</a>
  </fieldset>
</form>
<script src="../src/account.js">
</script>
```